# IFrame Error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, iframe, file-not-found

i got some error like this , when am trying to load an iframe source which is present in the folder . I tried everything since am new to php my knowledge is limited

my Php variable is passed to javascript variable

my php variable : 
$value_of_schedule = "Sat_20_30";

my javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){ 
    if(!$('#iframe').length) {
      var ValueOfSchedule_1 ="<?php echo json_encode($value_of_schedule); ?>";
       $('#iframeHolder').html('<iframe src ="../filemanager/logs/'+ValueOfSchedule_1+'/report.html"  height="1100px" width="100%">');
    }  
  });   
});
</script>
```

here if i give console.log , in log file it will retrieve schedulename , but in frame src it writtens as null , at can't access . if i run and inspect the iframe part it will show something like this :

```
<iframe src="../filemanager/logs/null/report.html" height="1100px" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: You likely want to quote that. `var ValueOfSchedule_1 = "<?php echo json_encode($value_of_schedule); ?>";`

Comment: Voting to close as typo-type question

Comment: <iframe src="../filemanager/logs/null/report.html" height="1100px" width="100%"></iframe>  -----> So it gives something like this

Comment: I edited the code as @mplungjan said

Comment: So did it work when you quoted it?

Comment: If not, look in the view-source to see. If  it says `var ValueOfSchedule_1 ="null";` then the issue is in the PHP

Comment: yeah i think its not passing the value to javascript

Comment: can someone help me in this .

Comment: Yes, you. Debug your php. It’s not likely a js issue after all